# Scripting language to interact with websites

Tags: web, interaction

I am trying to write a script to be able to automatically go to a website, fill in a form's fields, submit the form, login to my email and send and email.  Basic web interactivity. What language would you suggest that I use and also, how should I get started with writing this script?  (Do I need to install compilers, environments, etc.)

I have looked at AutoIt, Javascript and VBScript but they don't quite seem to do everything to the extent that I want.

Answer (score 1):

For browser automation try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest API for sending mails is apache commons mail http://commons.apache.org/email/
10 lines of code in java can do the trick.